# Regex to match the number between string and other number

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match only the number between a string and other number?

`RO41 RNCB 0089 0957 6044 0001                            FPS21098343 RO17 BTRL 0470 1202 W949 45XX`

What I want: `21098343`

What I'm trying LINK : `[0-9]{4}\s*\S+\s+(\S+)`

What I get: `FPS21098343`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `\b\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z]+(\d+)`? Or `\b\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z]+(\d+)$` / `(?m)\b\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z]+(\d+)$`.

Comment: You need `21098343`? You mentioned _"between"_, isn't it the last part of the string?

Comment: `(?m)\b\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z]+(\d+)$` worked, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the digits are at the end of the string `$` you could use :

```
\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ruq8o/1)

Or you can match uppercase chars preceding the digits and capture the digits in capture group 1 if it is not at the end of  string, not followed by a space and digit:

```
\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)\b(?!\s+\d)
```

- `\b\d{4}\s+` A word boundary, match 4 digits and 1+ whitespace chars
- `[A-Z]+(\d+)\b` Match 1+ uppercase chars and capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `(?!\s+\d)` Assert not whitespaces followed by a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J0t6Xn/1)

Comment: regexr.com/652qh hmm.. don't think the $ is helping that much since I have additional data in my document where I do the match

Comment: @shAkur If you want 949 `\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)\s+\S+$` https://regex101.com/r/BUyHrr/1

Comment: @shAkur I you want both `\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/7vdThz/1

Comment: I don't want the 949, I just want the number after `FPS`. i.e: `21098343`

Comment: @shAkur Then this will match only the number `\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)\s+[A-Z]` https://regex101.com/r/9CPd6t/1 or if it can also be the last field `\b\d{4}\s+[A-Z]+(\d+)\b(?!\s+\d)` https://regex101.com/r/J0t6Xn/1

Answer (score 0):

Match the number only if its preceded by 3 capital letters.

```
(?<=[A-Z]{3})([\d]+)
```

Sample run [here](https://regex101.com/r/gYf9wD/2)

Comment: here I have `FPS`.. but there could be any combination of 3 letters

Comment: I see. I updated the matcher to catch any group of 3 letters.